# Gridgain In-Memory Streaming deploiyng

Tags: gridgain

I'm trying to use Gridgain In-Memory Streaming and I can't understand ho w to deploy to cluster.
For example, I have cluster from two nodes:
 1) first node starts with streamer "TestStreamer"
 2) second node has identical streamer "TestStreamer"
 3) I'm changing some code of "TestStreamer" and redeploying it on first node

Is the possibility to autodeploy it on second node?

I've tried http://atlassian.gridgain.com/wiki/display/GG60/GridUriDeploymentSpi, but seems it works only for tasks, not for streamers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. If you need to change the streamer code in GridGain, then you need to restart the node with new code in the classpath.

Tasks, computations, and cache objects, on the other hand can be auto-deployed.